# Docker Remote API & Binds

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm trying to use Docker's Remote API via nodejs docker.io library but I just can't find the right syntax how to bind directories.

I'm currently using this code:

```
docker.containers.start(cId, { Binds: ['/tmp:/tmp'] }, function(err, container)...
```

It starts container but when I inspect it doesn't show anything in Volumes.

Docker's Remote API documentation is lacking when it comes to syntax so I'm hoping somebody here knows the correct syntax.

Answer (score 17):

I finally got it working. It seems you also need to create Volumes when you create the container. Here's the proper syntax:

> the first API call to /container/create should include:

```
{
    "Volumes": { "/container/path": {} }
}
```

> Then when starting a container (POST /containers//start), use the "Binds" option:

```
{
    "Binds": [ "/host/path:/container/path:rw" ]
}
```

source: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/docker-club/GrFQ3F1rqU4/3ZC5QoNkSAAJ

Comment: For any future visitors, If the folder is already persistent in the container, it just does not mount it