# Volumes not binding with the docker remote API

Tags: curl, docker

I am trying to use the docker remote API to bind volumes. I am following the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208297/docker-remote-api-binds) but it is still not working.

My test is running these two curl commands

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:4243/containers/create    
-d '{
  "Image" : "ubuntu",
  "Cmd" : [ "ls", "-la"],
  "Volumes": { "/mnt": {} },
  "WorkingDir" : "/mnt",
  "NetworkDisabled" : false
}'

curl -XPOST http://localhost:4243/containers/<whateverID>/start -d '{
    "Binds": [ "/tmp/:/mnt:ro" ]
}'
```

The documentation for the api is awful. If anyone can even point me to the revelent lines in the client code that would be something to work from. Has anyone else even gotten this working or is this a know issue?

Comment: Could you try to modify `/mnt`in both your **create** and **start** commands to a mountpoint/folder that doesn't already exists by default (`/textbind`for example)?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set your content type to application/json in your start request

Once you do this it should work.